# Elasticsearch never finishes indexing

Tags: elasticsearch, docker

I wanted to migrate my ES instance from one server to another (along with all the data).

So, following [the snapshot / restore api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html), I created a snapshot of the data on the old server, `scp`'d it to the new server, started up an instance of ES on the new server, restored the snapshot, and restarted ES on the new server.

The problem is ES never finishes indexing.  The number of `red` indices remains fixed after processing about 10 indices (I have about 300+ indices)

Side note, the new ES instance is running on docker on the new server, and the old ES instance was natively installed on the old server.

Comment: What do you get when running the following commands: `curl -XGET localhost:9200/_cat/indices/?v` and `curl -XGET localhost:9200/_cat/recovery/?v` and `curl -XGET localhost:9200/_cat/allocation/?v` ?

Answer (score 0):

This was so silly, but it's not really documented in the ES snapshot / restore documentation.

After [I called `/_snapshot/my_backup/snapshot_1/_restore` to restore my snapshot](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html#_restore) on the new server, all of the indices appeared as `yellow` status.  So I figured I had to stop ES and restart it to force it to re-index.

Well, that's not actually the case.  Once you call `_restore` on the instance, it starts indexing the data, and doesn't complete immediately, even though all of the indices status' are `yellow`.

As a result, when I killed my ES instance after calling `_restore`, only a few indexes were actually restored (i.e. the indexes ES had time to process between when I called `_restore` and when I killed it).  When ES started back up, it was only able to re-index those few indices it had time to process (and the rest I'm assuming were corrupted).

---

So the solution was simple: remove all of my data, start ES, call the snapshot `_restore` endpoint, and then ***patiently wait for ES to finish applying the restore***.

---

I was able to monitor the progress of the snapshot restore with this command:

`curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v&pretty' | egrep "(k|m)b" | sort | wc -l`

Once that number hit 0 I was good to go (`sort` because I like things orderly).

In hindsight, this solution is painfully obvious....